# Robust epipolar geometry estimation with scikit-image's ransac

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, scikit-image, ransac

I'm having trouble achieving robust performance with [`skimage.measure.ransac`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#ransac) when estimating fundamental matrix for a pair of images.
I'm seeing highly varying results with different random seeds when compared to OpenCV's [`findFundamentalMatrix`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga30ccb52f4e726daa039fd5cb5bf0822b).

I'm running both skimage's and opencv's ransac on the same sets of keypoints and with *(what I'm assuming are)* equivalent parameters.
I'm using the same image pair as [OpenCV python tutorials](https://github.com/abidrahmank/OpenCV2-Python-Tutorials/tree/master/data).

Here's my demonstration script:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

from skimage import io
from skimage.measure import ransac
from skimage.feature import ORB, match_descriptors
from skimage.transform import FundamentalMatrixTransform

orb = ORB(n_keypoints=500)

img1 = io.imread('images/right.jpg', as_grey=True)
orb.detect_and_extract(img1)
kp1 = orb.keypoints
desc1 = orb.descriptors

img2 = io.imread('images/left.jpg', as_grey=True)
orb.detect_and_extract(img2)
kp2 = orb.keypoints
desc2 = orb.descriptors

matches = match_descriptors(desc1, desc2, metric='hamming', cross_check=True)
kp1 = kp1[matches[:, 0]]
kp2 = kp2[matches[:, 1]]

n_iter = 10
skimage_inliers = np.empty((n_iter, len(matches)))
opencv_inliers = skimage_inliers.copy()

for i in range(n_iter):
    fmat, inliers = ransac((kp1, kp2), FundamentalMatrixTransform,
                           min_samples=8, residual_threshold=3,
                           max_trials=5000, stop_probability=0.99,
                           random_state=i)
    skimage_inliers[i, :] = inliers

    cv2.setRNGSeed(i)
    fmat, inliers = cv2.findFundamentalMat(kp1, kp2, method=cv2.FM_RANSAC,
                                           param1=3, param2=0.99)
    opencv_inliers[i, :] = (inliers.ravel() == 1)

skimage_sum_of_vars = np.sum(np.var(skimage_inliers, axis=0))
opencv_sum_of_vars = np.sum(np.var(opencv_inliers, axis=0))

print(f'Scikit-Image sum of inlier variances: {skimage_sum_of_vars:>8.3f}')
print(f'OpenCV sum of inlier variances:       {opencv_sum_of_vars:>8.3f}')
```

And the output:

```
Scikit-Image sum of inlier variances:   13.240
OpenCV sum of inlier variances:          0.000
```

I use the sum of variances of inliers obtained from different random seeds as the metric of robustness.

I would expect this number to be very close to zero, because truly robust ransac should converge to the same model, independent of it's random initialization.

How can I make skimage's `ransac` behave as robustly as opencv's?

---

My code is largely based on:

- [OpenCV-Python Epipolar Geometry tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_epipolar_geometry/py_epipolar_geometry.html#epipolar-geometry)
- [Scikit-Image Fundamental matrix estimation example](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/transform/plot_fundamental_matrix.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-transform-plot-fundamental-matrix-py)

---

late edit: I ended up asking the question on the skimage mailing list as well, and it turns out that the inconsistencies might be caused by different ways of calculating model error in each library.

This is doesn't answer my original question, so I'm not marking it as resolved, however I found it satisfying enough that I stopped pursuing further.

For anybody interested, Johannes from the mailing list suggests that reimplementing the residuum calculation in `FundamentalMatrixTransform` to use  point to epipolar line distance instead of Sampson error should be a step in the right direction.

Comment: There may be more problems under the hood, but it doesn't seem as though you correctly extract inliers in either the OpenCV nor the skimage case.  Both libraries return a mask.

Comment: @StefanvanderWalt I am aware of this. With a robust algorithm the mask shouldn't vary, so the variance of the mask is a reasonable metric, no?

Comment: @msladecek I'm not an expert on RANSAC, but what definitely shouldn't vary is the estimated transform, *not* which keypoints are selected. Can you check whether the fundamental matrices are similar each time? I also couldn't find an API reference for cv2 so I don't know whether the parameters actually do match.